# Why PollSkipStrategy.skipPoll method is getting called on every message polled from queue?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

I'm using inbound poller to process failed requests from backout queue. For scheduling, I'm using corn expression '0 0/2 * * * *' i.e. execute poller every two minutes. The scheduling is working fine as per corn, but PollSkipStrategy.skipPoll method is getting called for every message polled. I was under impression is, poll skip strategy will be execute once for each poll and not for each record polled. I have implementation for PollSkipStrategy.skipPoll, which returns true or false based on peoperty. I'm missing something here? Here is my configuration

```
    <bean id="RegistrationEventPoller"
        class="com.poller.RegistrationEventPoller">
        <property name="RegistrationEventRetryCount" value="$env{RegistrationEventRetryCount}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="PollSkipAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice">
        <constructor-arg ref="PollSkipStrategy"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="PollSkipStrategy"
        class="com..poller.PollSkipStrategy">
        <property name="RegistrationPollerOnOff" value="$env{RegistrationPollerOnOff}"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice is an around advice on the whole flow (`MessageSource.receive()` and sending the message). When the poller fires it calls the flow for up to `maxMessagesPerPoll` so, yes, the advice is actually called for each message found within the poll, not just on the first poll. It simply provides a mechanism to stop calling the message source if some condition prevents you from handling messages.

A more sophisticated [Smart Polling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) feature was added in 4.2 which gives you much more flexibility.

Comment: thank you, I'm using 4.6.1 and upgrade is not in plan in near future. However, to reduce resource usage, I'll see if other options are available, e.g. use feature toggle to read from db and cache for pool skip advice.